# Указание правильного пути к файлу в jsp

Tags: java, css, сервер, jsp, link

Пытаюсь в `.jsp` указать правильный путь до `.css`.
Когда указываю содержание своего файла стилей просто в `<head>`, все работает (могу отличить рабочую версию от нерабочей).
Но когда пытаюсь достучаться до самого файла, ничего не выходит.
Вот путь до файла: `src/webapp/style.css`.
А путь до jsp: `src/webapp/first.jsp`
Вот так пытался достучаться до него.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style.css" />`
```

и вот так.

```
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**Содержание моего jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class ="header">
      <nav class="docs-navigation mdl-navigation">
               <a href="./map.jsp" class="mdl-navigation__link about">About</a>
               <a href="./map.jsp" class="mdl-navigation__link started">Getting Started</a>
     </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Some text to enable scrolling.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ссылки при этом работают нормально.

**Содержание style.css:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Roboto; 
    src: url(${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Roboto-Light.ttf); 
   }
 h1{
    font-family: Roboto;
   }
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
.header {
    top:0px;
    height:15%;
    position:fixed;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 85%;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
```

А вот ссылка на файл с шрифтом не срабатывает.

Что мне сделать, чтобы нормально функционировало?

**UPD:**
Попытки задать background картинкой из папки с ресурсами тоже не срабатывают. В чем причина?

Comment: 'href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style.css" />', а что это за кавычки вокруг ссылки? Если они в коде, то уберите их.

Comment: @webaib, да там что с кавычками, что без. Не работает...

Comment: что то у вас конкретно не правильно настроено, т.к. это переменная должна быть доступна в jsp. А вот в css вы ее зря пихнули, там ее некому обработать.

Answer (score 1):

у вас "корень" приложения в `src/webapp/` в корне лежит и `.jsp` и `.css`, путь к `.css` надо прописывать от корня, вместо:

```
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

надо

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Не работает. Возможно, вам код запуска Jetty кинуть?

Comment: посмотрите про [маппинг ресурсов в Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958251/map-jetty-resourcehandler-to-a-url)